# Is it possible to auto implement a trait which casts a trait object to another trait object?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, boilerplate, trait-objects

I have a trait which manages conversions to different trait objects.
The trait looks like this: (`Boo` and `Gee` are both different Traits)

```
trait Foo {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        None
    }

    fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee> {
        None
    }
}
```

To reduce the amount of boilerplate code I now want to automatically change this implementation to this in case the struct implements `Boo`/`Gee`:

```
#[derive(Boo)]
struct W {}

impl Foo for W {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
```

I could do this if there is only one other trait I have to convert to by using generics:

```
impl<T: Boo> Foo for T {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
```

But in case I also want to automatically implement `Foo` for `Gee` it doesn't work this way due to the fact that I could not implement `Foo` twice, which is not supported by rust as far as I know.

```
// This does not compile because Foo might get implemented twice.
impl<T: Boo> Foo for T {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

impl<T: Gee> Foo for T {
    fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
```

It might be possible to achieve this using [`Procedural Macros`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/procedural-macros.html) but I could not find any in depth explanation of them so I am kind of stuck now.

Comment: As far as I know procedural macros don't have access to type information, so you will not be able to decide whether the type needs to override default method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by [introducing an extra level of indirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_software_engineering):

```
trait Boo {}
trait Gee {}

trait FooAsBoo {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        None
    }
}

trait FooAsGee {
    fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee> {
        None
    }
}

trait Foo: FooAsBoo + FooAsGee {}

impl<T: Boo> FooAsBoo for T {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

impl<T: Gee> FooAsGee for T {
    fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

impl<T: FooAsBoo + FooAsGee> Foo for T {} // if there's nothing else in Foo

struct W;
impl Boo for W {}
impl Gee for W {}

fn main() {
    let mut w = W;
    let foo = &mut w as &mut Foo;
    let boo = foo.as_boo();
}
```

By moving `as_boo` and `as_gee` each to their own trait, we avoid the overlapping implementations. Methods from supertraits are available in trait objects, so `Foo` doesn't have to redeclare `as_boo` and `as_gee`.

---

> While this works great in cases where `Boo` and `Gee` are *close* to always implemented, it still requires manual implementation when this is not the case. Considering the fact that as_gee should return `None` in about 80% of all calls in my program this is rather unfortunate.

We can solve this by using [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) (which is not stable as of Rust 1.19, so you'll need to use the nightly compiler). We need to move the implementations of `as_boo` and `as_gee` from the trait definition to an `impl` that applies to all types, so that all types implement `FooAsBoo` and `FooAsGee`.

```
#![feature(specialization)]

trait FooAsBoo {
    fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo>;
}

trait FooAsGee {
    fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee>;
}

impl<T> FooAsBoo for T {
    default fn as_boo(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Boo> {
        None
    }
}

impl<T> FooAsGee for T {
    default fn as_gee(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Gee> {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works great in cases where `Boo` and `Gee` are *close to* always implemented, it still requires manual implementation when this is not the case. Considering the fact that `as_gee` should return `None` in about 80% of all calls in my program this is a rather unfortunate.